# Manejo de datos arrays, maps - CVS

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsf

Tengo varias dudas respecto a cómo manejar un módulo de registros en mi aplicación, dado que el requerimiento indica que se debe cargar un archivo *CVS* con aproximadamente *18mil a 20mil* registros. El cargado del archivo se debe realizar en una aplicación *JSF*, con *PrimeFaces* y *MySql*. Posteriormente, a través de un *SP* que realiza la lógica de inserción en base de datos de acuerdo a ciertas características propias de la información dada.

La pregunta sería, si bien uno lee el archivo y utiliza ciertas librerías... ¿Cuál sería la más óptima? ¿Qué tipo de *Lista, map, etc*, se debería usar para esa cantidad de registros?

Comment: Tal vez querías decir un archivo csv en vez de un archivo cvs

Answer (score 0):

Luego de cargar el archivo, una forma rápida de grabar los registros es utilizar una carga masiva (Bulk):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'TuArchivo.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_TuTabla
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

puedes revisar estos links:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html